# Implement enumerable/collection class in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to implement class (implements SequenceType), and it seems to be a bit complicated than I was expecting. In C# I just need to implement `IEnumerable` and "`yield return`" makes it quite easy. The same in python with `__iter__()` and with `yield`. But in Swift I don't know why it happens to be overly complicated.
Here is the code

```
class Nums : SequenceType{

    let list = [1,2,3,4,5]

    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<Int?> {

        return GeneratorOf<Int?>{

            for i in self.list{
                return i
            }

            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

When I am calling it in `for-in` it goes into infinite loop.

What is the proper way if implementing iterable classes in swift ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`return` inside a generator does not work like `yield` in C#, Python, and other languages. It's just a plain `return` statement.

Instead, Swift generators use optional vaules — `Some(x)` indicates the next item in the sequence, and `None` (or `nil`) signals the end of the sequence.

The block you pass to the `GeneratorOf<Int>` constructor (by the way, there is no need to use `Int?`) will be called *at each step*, and should produce the next value each time it is called, or `nil` when it's done. So, you can use a mutable variable to keep track of state:

```
func generate() -> GeneratorOf<Int>
{
    var i = 0

    return GeneratorOf<Int> {
        if i >= self.list.count { return nil }
        return self.list[i++]
    }
}
```

Or you can even use your `list`'s built-in generator:

```
func generate() -> GeneratorOf<Int>
{
    var g = self.list.generate()

    return GeneratorOf<Int> {
        return g.next() // not very exciting... we might as well have returned g itself
    }
}
```